How can I see the variables values as they change in OpenSolver
I am trying to use OpenSolver in Excel VBA (I know is old and unsuported but is free).
I am running an optimization using the code I wrote, however the variables don't seem to change. I need to know where OpenSolver changes variables values.
Any ideas?
Thank you

Assuming you are solving a linear programme, then you cannot see the variables change on the spreadsheet. This is because, OpenSolver gives your problem to a "solver", and then gets back an answer. But, you can turn on "Show optimisation progress while solving" under the OpenSolver... Options menu to see the output that the solver produces.
You will be pleased to know a new version going to be released later this year that includes a number of small improvements, including support for the new HiGHs solver.
Hope this helps,
Andrew

Great, Thank you!
Looking forwards to see the new version.
It would be nice though if one could see the variable change as the optimization orogresses. This information is very important since no optimization is perfect and sometimes, the optimization imput parameters might be changed to improve the  convergence behavior.
Do the developers accept "feature requests?"?
